# Erro redirecionamento express

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I have the following code snippet for two routes:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    querySelectUsers(req.body['email'], 0, 0, function (result) {
        if (result.exist && result.password === req.body['senha']) {
            delete result.email, result.password
            res.cookie("userData", result.token, { expire: 600000 + Date.now() });
            res.redirect('/agendamentos')
        } else {
            res.send(false)
        }
    })
})
```

and

```
router.get('/agendamentos', function (req, res) {
    if(req.cookies.userData){
        res.sendFile('./marcacao/agendamentos.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../src/public') });
    }else{
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
})
```

When performing the procedure of the login route of receiving a post, I do not have the expected return
The procedure happens to validate the users, set the cookie, but the redirection to the HTML reservas.html does not occur, it just updates the login page and adds a ? in the url.

Comment: I don't see any redirect to "reservas.html" in the code you posted

Comment: Sorry, my intention is to redirect the page to "/agendamentos" and if the route validates, return the html "agendamentos.html" using the function res.senFile()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After some research I discovered the real error that is harming me.

What is actually happening is that my '/login' route is not being recognized by my server.